# How to submit hive query to spark thrift server?

Tags: apache-spark

Here is the short story:

A BI tool (PowerBI) connects to Spark cluster and uses HiveThriftServer2 application to get aggregated data via hive queries.

However, each query takes a lot of time since every time it reads data from files. I would like to cache my table in this application and looking for the way to send query "cache table myTable" through same channel, so next queries will run quick.

What would be a solution to send hive query to specific application? If it matters, the application is a thrift service of Spark.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: P.S. I've tried to use beeline, but it opens another application using Tez

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I succeed to do it, by installing Spark Odbc driver and using it to connect to thift server and send the sql query "cache table xxx". I wonder if there is more elegant way

Comment: How about running an intermediary backend rest or jdbc service in  that controls your spark resources (spark thrift server and spark executors); also reads query that is generated by your BI tool; this way you can control lot of things like throttling; queueing, caching